# Detecting if period exists in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I apologize if this seems like a dumb question, but how would I go about searching a string to see if it contains a period? I've tried searching:

```
var p="This is text without a period, What now?"

alert(p.search("."));
```

I was under the impression that it should return -1 because there is no period in that sentence. However, it always returns 0.

Am I missing something?

Comment: FYI, the `search` method is a regular expression search, not a character match. In a regex, `.` matches *any* character, including that first "T".

Comment: Ahhhh, that explains it! Thanks for that.

Answer (score 11):

There's many ways to do this, I would probably use [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) just to see if a character exists in a string :

```
alert( p.indexOf(".") != -1 ); // true or false
```

According to MDN, [search()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) "Executes the search for a match between a regular expression and this String object.", so that would be :

```
alert( p.search(/\./) );
```

which would give you `-1`, and the period has special meaning in a regex, and must be escaped.

Comment: Great. Thanks. I forgot about the indexOf function... I'll mark it correct once they let me...

Comment: @Yatrix It gets upvoted quickly because there were 7 other people typing up the same answer, he just hit submit the fastest. :)

Comment: @KevinB still makes me insanely jealous!

Comment: @Yatrix Write better answers then `;)`

Comment: @Yatrix - often times simple answers to generic questions generates more points, and sometimes you can work for a long time on an answer, trying to figure something out, and you finally get it, and noone else has answered, and you end up not getting a single upvote, as everyone has moved along, and the OP does'nt even bother to accept it. That's just how it is!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick to regex, you will need to escape the `.`, as it is a special regex character. To escape the dot in JavaScript Regex, you need to "cast" it to a character class. This is done via `[]`.

```
alert(p.search("[.]"));
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexflav23/qCmwW/)

Answer (score 0):

use `indexOf()` method of a string for this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf